# What is the difference between a method and a proc object?

Tags: ruby, methods, lambda, proc

I know that methods in Ruby are not objects but procs and lambdas are. Is there any difference between them other than that? Because both we can pass around. What makes the proc objects different from a method?

Method:

```
1.8.7-p334 :017 > def a_method(a,b)
1.8.7-p334 :018?>   puts "a method with args: #{a}, #{b}"
1.8.7-p334 :019?>   end
1.8.7-p334 :021 > meth_ref = Object.method("a_method")
 => #<Method: Class(Object)#a_method> 
1.8.7-p334 :022 > meth_ref.call(2,3)
```

Proc Object:

```
  a = lambda {|a, b| puts "#{a}, #{b}"}
  a.call(2,3)
```

Comment: Am not asking for proc and lambda. I'm asking difference between a method and a proc object.

Comment: without understanding how can they mark as duplicate :( I missed out many answers. Is my question valid?

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
`a = Proc.new{ | a, b | puts "#{a}, #{b}" }`
I think the title of the questions means we are talking about "Proc[s]", not "lambda".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In brief:**

a `Method` object is "bound" to an object so that `self` points to that object when you `call` the method, and a `Proc` doesn't have that behavior; `self` depends on the context in which the `Proc` was created/called.

**However:**

You said in your question that "methods are not objects," but you have to be careful to distinguish between "method" and `Method`.

A "method" is a defined set of expressions that is given a name and put into the method table of a particular class for easy lookup and execution later:

```
class Foo
  def my_method
    return 123
  end
end

Foo.new.my_method
# => 123
```

A `Method` object (or similarly an `UnboundMethod` object) is an actual Ruby object created by calling `method` / `instance_method` / etc. and passing the name of a "method" as the argument:

```
my_Foo = Foo.new

my_Method = my_Foo.method(:my_method)
# => #<Method: Foo#my_method>

my_Method.call
# => 123

my_UnboundMethod = Foo.instance_method(:my_method)
# => #<UnboundMethod: Foo#my_method>

my_UnboundMethod.bind(my_Foo).call
# => 123
```

A `Proc` object is a set of expressions that is not given a name, which you can store for later execution:

```
my_proc = Proc.new { 123 }
my_proc.call
# => 123
```

You may find it useful to read the RDoc documentation for [`UnboundMethod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html), [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html), and [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html). The RDoc pages list the different instance methods available to each type.

Comment: In which situations we use Method  to create a method?

Answer (score 1):

**Differences between blocks and procs**

1. Procs are objects, blocks are not
2. At most one block can appear in an argument list

**Differences between procs and lambdas**

1. Lambdas check the number of arguments, while procs do not
2. Lambdas and procs treat the `return` keyword differently

It is very well explained here (I just copied that from the link below)

http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/

Comment: Here am not asking for a proc,lambda and block. I want to know the difference between a method and a proc object

Comment: @Kranthi I'm sorry. I missunderstood you. I will fix my answer as soon as I get home.

Comment: @Verhaeren not yet reached home?